# Spring Webflux: HandlerFilterFunction How they designed the filter to be execute before the handlers?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

(This is not a question about WebFilter, this is about FilterHandlerFunctions: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-filters)

I Have a class that is my router to the endpoints:

```
@Configuration
class QuotationRouter(val testHandlerFilter : TestHandlerFilter) {


    @Bean
    @QuotationDocs
    fun quotationRoutes(handler: QuotationHandler) = coRouter {
        val path = "/test"
        accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
            "$path/quotation".nest {
                POST("approve", handler::approve)
                POST("deny", handler::deny)
                POST("pending", handler::pending)
                POST("canceled", handler::canceled)
            }
        }
    }.filter(testHandlerFilter)
}
```

I created a filter that validates if the call has the header that I am wanted and the value that we store. Like this:

```
@Component
class TestHandlerFilter(
    @Value("\${test.headerName:test}") private val headerName: String = "test",
    @Value("\${test.tokenValue:test}") private val tokenValue: List<String> = emptyList()
    ) : HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {


    override fun filter(request: ServerRequest, next: HandlerFunction<ServerResponse>): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        request.headers().firstHeader(headerName)?.run {
            if (!tokenValue.contains(this)) {
                return ServerResponse.status(ReasonCode.UNAUTHORIZED_RESPONSE.status).bodyValue(Pair("message", ReasonCode.UNAUTHORIZED_RESPONSE.description))
            }
            return next.handle(request)
        } ?: return ServerResponse.status(ReasonCode.FORBIDDEN_RESPONSE.status).bodyValue(Pair("error", ReasonCode.FORBIDDEN_RESPONSE.description))
    }
}
```

I tested and the filter is always executed first and then the routerHandler. This is what I'm looking for. However, I have no idea how this is made, because I put the filter() function in the end of coRouter.

I wonder to ask you what is missing in my understanding that could answer this question:

- How the filter is executing first but he was put on the end of the instructions? This part of functional style?

Thanks.

Comment: Because you have annotated the class as an `@Component` which means it is automatically registered by spring. Then you ALSO manually register it. Why you are doing both i have no idea

Comment: Well, I just need to put like this (using `@component` in one and, another using `@Configuration` in order to inject the filter on handler by constructor), however, I refactored this code, just to organize better, but I needed to maintain this similar use.

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean? `Well, I just need to put like this (using @component in one and, another using @Configuration in order to inject the filter on handler by constructor)` I dont really understand this statement